# Multipeer connectivity framework via bluetooth in iOS: how to determine if the message is "old"?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, network-programming, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

I have one device (server) which can send messages and they should appear on other devices.

The problem is all the devices are connected via bluetooth. It means the server can't send the messages directly to a destination but it may send messages via a number other of devices.

But the following situation may occur:

1)S (server) sends message1 to A.

2)S sends message1 to B.

3)S don't see A so it sends message2 to B only (message2 should overwrite message1).

4)Finally B sees A and sends message2. So how should A define is message2 is older than message1 or vice versa?

The only way I found is to add to each message a timestamp from server. Is it really the only one way?

Comment: Typically time stamp is the way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I see two general options:

1. If the server is the only origin of messages you could also use sequence numbers instead of a timestamp.
2. If there are multiple origins the sequence could be bound to a unique identification of the server so both values are still unique in their combination.

Example for multiple origins (A, B):

```
A:1, A:2, A:3, A:4, ...
B:1, B:2, B:3, ...
```

Each origin could have individual (overlapping) sequence numbers. 
The combination of origin id + sequence makes them unique again (compound key).

Pros/Cons:

1. timestamp: +easy to generate, -possible duplicates on high traffic and low granularity
2. sequence: +probably shorter than timestamp, +always unique, -requires compound key for multiple origins

Comment: The first part - timestamp is already any number even if it is any/incorrect. The app need to increment it each time only. And I can't understand your second part. Could you explain it in other words?

Comment: Just added some explanation. See above.

Comment: Still can't understand. It seems you suggest to simply rewrite message with a new one but how to recognize if the node gets a newer message and then it gets an older one?

Comment: I don't suggest anything about what you do when an older message appears. Your question was how to detect an older message. You need some kind of sequence that is strictly monotonically increasing: either a natural one (timestamp) or an artificial (self generated sequence number). Newer means higher number.

Comment: Ok, "how to detect an older message". The first node sends messages in the following order: msg1, msg2. The second node receives them in another order: msg2, msg1. So I already knew the first part of your answer (almost nothing new) and the second part is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Right. You already mentioned timestamp. This should work as long as each message gets an individual timestamp. Sequences should also work. If you think they wouldn't where is your issue? Or what keeps you from using the timestamp if you already had that in mind? Maybe I missed a detail in your case. If so, could you please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve and why neither timestamp or sequence number are satisfactory for you?